# autobench on HTTPS endpoint

Tags: ssl, https, load-testing, httperf, autobench

How do I set in autobench that I'm testing an `HTTPS` (port `443`) URL?

When I call it with:

```
autobench --single_host --host1 host.com --port1 443 --uri1 /hello --num_conn 1000 --timeout 5 --low_rate 10 --high_rate 50 --rate_step 10 --num_call 10 --quiet --file results.tsv
```

it shows:

```
httperf.parse_status_line: invalid status line `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">'!!
httperf.parse_status_line: bad status 1
```

Which is not correct because that `HTTPS` page (in the example above would be `https://host.com/hello`) returns a valid `200 OK` response.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following line to your `~/.autobench.conf` file:

```
httperf_ssl = NULL
```

`--ssl` is a command-line argument of `httperf`, which autobench calls underneath.  The `NULL` value means to not pass a value for that arg to `httperf`.

Generally speaking, you can add any additional command-line arguments to `httperf` by putting them in the config file and prepending them with `httperf_`.  Another example:

```
httperf_add-header = "Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg=="
```

is equivalent to running `httperf --add-header "Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg=="`